# Selenium Windows Save/Open Open Dialogue

Tags: selenium

I am trying to use selenium webdriver to automate web application. So say the dialog below pops up, my goal is to automatically click Save File, and then hit Ok.

Windows Save/Open File DownloadDialouge

Answer (score 3):

WebDriver cannot directly interact with dialog windows this is because dialog windows are the domain of the operating system and not the webpage. However its possible to do actions on dialog windows using 
SendKeys class method SendWait() of name space System.Windows.Forms

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

In the example code below a PLUpload button is pressed, which opens a Windows Dialog to select the file to upload.

Following lines are used to send key values to the dialog window displayed.

```
SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Dock.jpg");
SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

Detailed reference of SendKeys class in C# can be found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace BusinessCreation
{
    class PlUpload
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
               IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
               driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.plupload.com/example_queuew               idget.php");
               driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//object[@data='/plupload/js/pluploa               d.flash.swf']")).Click();
               SendKeys.SendWait(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Dock               .jpg");
               SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with Selenium on it's own.

You'll have to combine it with AutoIT:

http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

(or something similar).

I'd also point out for majority of cases you can get away with simply 'sending' (using the 'Send Keys' method/function in your particular language bindings) the file path direct to the upload control, ensuring you *do not* click the actual `Browse...` button. Once you do, it's game over for Selenium.

Comment: Thanks Arran. I just got this link on google. It has sample code for Auto Savehttp://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Snippets_(_Files_%26_Folders_)#File_Open.2FSave.2FFolder_Dialog_Box

Answer (score 0):

//File Save Code

```
FirefoxProfile profile =new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreferences("browser.download.folderlist",0);

profile.setpreferences("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",mimeType);//applicatio/zip

WebDriver driver = new FireforDriver(profile);

driver.get("http:seleniumhq.org/download");

driver.get("http://selenium.com/files/selenium.zip");
```

//File Open Code

```
profile.setPreferences("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.open",mimeType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Method for file handling:

We need :

jacob.jar [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/%E2%80%8E)

It will contain one jar file and 2 .dll files

AutoItX4Java.jar [Download](https://code.google.com/p/autoitx4java/downloads/list)

```
public static void uploadFile(String path, String browser){

if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

    if(x.winWaitActive("Open", "", 10)){
        if(x.winExists("Open")){
            x.sleep(500);
            x.send(path);
            x.controlClick("Open", "", "Button2");

        }
    }

}


if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){

    if(x.winWaitActive("File Upload", "", 10)){
        if(x.winExists("File Upload")){
            x.sleep(500);
            x.send(path);
            x.controlClick("File Upload", "", "Button2");

        }
    }
}

if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer")){

    if(x.winWaitActive("Choose File to Upload", "", 10)){
        if(x.winExists("Choose File to Upload")){
            x.sleep(500);
            x.send(path);
            x.controlClick("Choose File to Upload", "", "Button2");

        }
    }
}



}


public void test(){
    //Click on the Select button of the file upload
    uploadFile("Path", "chrome");


}
```

Thanks... Dont click Accept or Upvote until it works for you. If it is not working for you means, please comment.. Dont Downvote...