# How to simulate key press in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I've been search in internet for 2 hours or something like that and now I'm a bit frustrated. Sorry if the answer is "duplicated" but I can't find what I want in anywhere and I'm a bit newbie in c# so.

I have to automate a process in internet explorer, the problem is when I have to download an excel file to work with it, I don't know how can I select de "Save" option in the pop-up of open, save, save as...

I try

```
SendKeys.SendWait(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Down.ToString());
SendKeys.SendWait(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter.ToString());
```

and the same with `SendKeys.Send(...);` the system not simulate the down or enter, but If i do it with keyboard it works, what I want exactly is to simulate keyboard key pressing with down arrow and then enter.

((Sorry if my english is bad)) 
[POP UP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v38Z4.png)

I think that I can solve the problem if I press the save option ("guardar") simulating keyboard presses, I need to download the file but I don't know how, It have to be all automatic process without user intervention that will enter into a database fields of excel automatically every hour.

Comment: Can you please explain more, what is your actual problem, it seems that simulating keypress is not the solution.

Comment: I will edit the post, w8 a moment :$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle downloading a file in selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510816/how-to-handle-downloading-a-file-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp) and is it work for what you want to do?

Comment: Keypress isn't the the issue. Your problem is you want to download a file, the solution isn't to press Save it's to get selenium (the browser) to download the file without the popup

Comment: And, how can I get the download without the popup, the web only works on internet explorer, I search for that and i have been unable to get any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You should find a node in html code

```
<input id='fileupload'>
```

or something like that. 
Then may use

```
driver.FindElement().SendKeys(type absolute path to folder where do you want save file)
```

This is the easiest solution but if you must handling dialog you can take a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576430/selenium-windows-save-open-open-dialogue) or similar post related to this topic (selenium dialog window)